# Configure logback through Eclipse for Tomcat logging

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, logback

I configured my logback.xml to create a ATSLog.log file and save every day a log file with the date.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/ATSLog.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/ATSLog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </FileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" />
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But in my /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/logs I find only one old ATSLog.log and no other log saved. Do you see an error in my configuration?
Thanks

Comment: `CATALINA_BASE` environment variable is present? also check if `/logs/ATSLog.log` this file exist?

Comment: if I use printenv I receive only CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26 and not base, I try to add (maybe was deleted from last time that I control two month ago) and tomorrow check if it stores the actual log and creates the new

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `CATALINA_BASE` in you environment variables. In your config file you have specified the log file path relative to `CATALINA_BASE` using the expression `${catalina.base}`. If its not in environment variables, try adding it. If not set, you can probably expect the logs in `/log/ATSLogs.log`.

Comment: I updated with CATALINA_HOME and with the date into log file but I find only a ATSLog with no date field and there aren't yesterday ATSLog file

Answer (score 0):

Try this project:  https://github.com/grgrzybek/tomcat-slf4j-logback

This project provides the necessary JAR files and configuration files to integrate you instance of Tomcat with SLF4J + Logback, replacing the logging code embedded within the default Tomcat distribution.  Refer to the Quick Start section of that project's README for instructions and download links.

I've used it on production and Eclipse environments with much success.  Note the extra steps at the bottom of the project's README file for Eclipse environments.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I've added a brief description of what that project is about.  Let me know if this is the level of detail that is needed.  That project is essentially the solution and reiterating the instructions from there is not a good idea IMHO.